# Override GCC's varargs argument promotion

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

I'm working on a piece of code for an ARM processor running the Cortex-M4 architecture (has single precision floats but not double). The issue I'm running into is when using varargs and the compiler tries to promote my floats into doubles. Is there any way to turn this off? Or specify a different promotion strategy? I've looked in the GCC manuals but couldn't find anything. A simple example is trying to write your own printf...

```
void myprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
  // .. parse fmt and come across %f

  double dv = va_arg(args, double); // Compiles but doesn't link

  float fv = va_arg(args, float); // Doesn't compile (warns about promotion)
}
```

UPDATE: As requested, the call command I'm looking to use is `myprintf("%f", 1.0f);`. The issue is that the Cortex-M4 doesn't support doubles, so when 1.0f is promoted to a double... well it can't. So reading it back using `va_arg(args, double)` will compile but won't link as the various `__aeabi_` functions related to doubles don't exist. What I want to do is disable GCC's promotion of floats to doubles (if possible).

UPDATE: I have a current workaround that basically just accepts pointers to floats instead of floats. I'd still like to disable the promotion as this isn't a great solution.

Comment: Please show how you call that. Maybe using the right kind of float (e.g. `1.0f` instead of `1.0`) helps.

Comment: Perhaps a wrapper around the `float` arg to use a compound literal `((float){arg})` and then pass the address of the compound literal?

Comment: If the target processor doesn't support doubles, why doesn't the compiler know this?

Comment: Shouldn't it just implement `double` as a synonym for `float`?

Comment: I agree with "should" but it doesn't. Updated question with current workaround

Comment: Could you provide us your compile-options? I would expect gcc to be smart enough to typedef float and double, when invoked with `-march=armv7e-m` - but I haven't done any testing yet.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar - if the compiler targets a platform that does not support double-precision, it makes sense for that compiler to map double to float.  Perhaps reaching out to the folks maintaining the ARM code in GCC for that platform can lead to having it changed.

Comment: What is the result of running the code that promotes a float to a double?  Illegal instruction?

Comment: OK, I see it now `__aeabi_` is undefined.  That's a tool-chain miss I believe.  Either the compiler should not generate a call to a function that does not exist, or the function should be written.

Comment: `the compiler tries to promote my floats into doubles` - it doesn't "try", it literally has to do this `Is there any way to turn this off?` - yes, change the C standard. And, please, if you can, invent a time machine and do it.

Comment: Have you investigated the `-mfloat-abi` options?  It should be possible to perform `double` processing in software,  which whilst slow , will at least compile and run correctly. Of course, you'll need to use system libraries compiled with the same ABI option(s)

Comment: Which GCC distribution are you using? The one [provided](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) by ARM is perfectly capable of `printf ()`-formatting doubles on Cortex-M4, even with using the existing single precision hardware float. Pass `-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp4-sp-d16` to *both* compiler and linker, and `-u _printf_float` to the linker. Also remember to enable the FPU coprocessor in the start-up code (assembler).

Comment: Yes it's capable of printf, though I'm not sure how. Printf in this example is just an example, I really just care about paying floats into varargs.

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer It does the `double` stuff in software, and `float` in hardware. I think `float` via vararg is not possible. But in C++, you can use variadic templates to pass any type, including `float`. You could use that as a wrapper for further non-template processing. If you specify what exactly you want to do with variadic arguments, I could give an example.

Answer (score 6):

Converting vararg `float` arguments to `double` is not a gcc quirk or add-on. It is required by the C standard. §6.5.2.3 (Function calls):

> 6. If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have  type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*. …
> 7. If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. **The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.**

Gcc does provide a few options which are not compatible with the C standard, but the vast majority add behaviour only in cases where the standard fails to do so. A change of this magnitude would affect the standard calling convention, making the compiled code incompatible with other compiled code such as libraries, standard or otherwise. Gcc does not provide such an option. Other compilers might, but I don't know of any which do.

Note that it is not possible, within the constraints of the standard, to just make`double` a synonym for `float` if `float` is a 32-bit value. The minimum precision requirements in §5.2.4.2.2 effectively require that a double have at least a 32-bit mantissa in addition to the exponent and sign. That's a lot less precision than is provided by 64-bit IEEE-749 doubles, but it's obviously more than can be provided in a 32-bit value.

It would certainly be possible for a compiler to provide an option where `double`s are represented in a less precise and computationally faster format, such as two `float`s where the mantissas don't overlap. (That is, the exponents differ by at least the width of the mantissa.) That representation, or something similar, was used by at least one legacy implementation IIRC, precisely because it allows single-precision hardware to be used for double-precision computation. It also makes casting a `float` to a `double` trivial; it's only necessary to make the low-order value 0.0. Alternatively, a compiler could use a 32-bit mantissa combined with a `short` exponent, which allows use of the integer ALU.

I don't believe GCC offers that alternative either, though.

Comment: The C standard is irrelevant. The question does not ask for a C-standard solution. It asks for a GCC solution. GCC already implements a variety of behaviors that are variations from the C standard, not extensions to it. This would just be one more. (Each combination of GCC switches constitutes a different C implementation. Some of them conform to the C standard, modulo bugs and other deficiencies. Some of them do not.)

Comment: I have to agree here as I'm looking for the same solution, with a very good reason - I need to be able to pass floats instead of doubles, and I control the whole environment from _start to finish. Let's find a solution!

Comment: @gonzo: I don't know if you solved your problem or just moved on, but now that I've stumbled upon this old answer and your comment, here's a suggestion: create a `struct` containing a single `float`, using something like `typedef struct { float v } FloatS;`. Arguments of that type will not be promoted, and they can be created using C99's compound literal format (`(FloatS){1.0f}`). (You could use a macro to reduce but not eliminate clutter. `#define F_(f) (FloatS){f})` would let you write a `myprintf` which accepted `myprintf("%F", F_(1.0f));}`.) Maybe I'll add that to the answer.